# DolphinDB - Fill missing values of a sequence

Tags: sql, left-join, dolphindb

I have a table t

```
t=table(100 101 103 106 as price,take(10,4) as n)

    price n
    100   10
    101   10
    103   10
    106   10
```

For the missing values of the column price, like 102, 104, and 105, I want to fill it with n=0.

```
price  n
100    10
101    10
102    0
103    10
104    0
105    0
106    10
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how will you generate the price seq, but you can do something like:

```
t=table(100 101 103 106 as price,take(10,4) as n)
t2=table(100..106 as price)
select price, n.nullFill(0) from t2 left join t on t2.price = t.price
```